# Setting meta field value to integer using the bulk editor

Tags: shopify

So basically as the title states I am trying to set the value of a meta field to an integer using the bulk editor.

The blog post I found on how to use the bulk editor for meta fields (https://www.shopify.com.au/partners/blog/53573123-secrets-of-the-shopify-bulk-editor) uses the following example to create a new metafield with a value that is a string but from what I can see there do not provide any examples for integers:

```
https://shopify.com/admin/bulk?resource_name=Product&edit=metafields.global.isbn:string
```

I've tried simply changing the :string part to :integer and :int but that didn't work.

I've searched around the internet and can't find any solutions, so I thought I would try here. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading those documents is seems like this shortcut method uses the word ***number***.

Comment: Ah yep, I was searching for integer and completely skipped over number. Thanks!

It appears to only set the value to an integer for newly created meta fields and won't change from a string if a string value has already been set. So I had to delete my existing created fields then set it to number.